# vectors and structures C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file,

```
cat molly
dog benji
bird charlie (etc..)
```

in another text file, "one day cat went out to lie in the sun - dog was already in the garden..." (etc..)

I am supposed to replace the animal with it's name. At the moment I am reading in the file and placing the animal type in one vector and the animal name in another vector.  My question is - do I need to put them in a structure so that when I loop through and find cat I can find the associated name - or do I use another method.  I've heard of multidimensional vectors but feel it may be over my head as I am very new to programming.

Comment: For data structure, I would recommend you look into [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: i am not using classes in my code, i am absolute beginner when it comes to programming i find the information in the link too complex to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the most appropriate structure for you to use would be a map. It would allow you  to associate an animal with a name and easily and efficiently look up the animal's name.

Try this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> animal_names;
```

The first template type is the *key* type and the second one is the *value* type. In your case, the keys are animals and the values are names.

You can then insert associations with this:

```
animal_names["cat"] = "molly";
```

Very simple! Note that if you now iterate over the map, you will get them in order of animal. That is `"bird"` will come first, then `"cat"`, then `"dog"`.

If you don't care about the order at all, you can instead use an `std::unordered_map`. This will improve the access and insertion time.

---

Since you say you are a beginner, I'll give you an example of how I would read your file:

```
std::ifstream file("animal_names.txt");
std::string animal, name;
std::map<std::string, std::string> animal_names;

while (file >> animal >> name) {
  animal_names[animal] = name;
}
```

Later, if you want to print out, for example, the name of the cat, just do:

```
std::cout << animal_names["cat"] << std::endl;
```

Comment: where it says animal_names, instead of ["cat"] i would need the vector name wouldn't i?

Comment: @Shiver There is no vector any more. We're replacing both of your vectors with this single map.

Comment: @Shiver I've added an example of how his is used. Looks simple, right?

Comment: Yes, thankyou very much :) I find that as all you programmers are really smart, you're answers are sometimes too expert for beginners but this is perfect, thankyou :)

Answer (score 2):

To *map* types of animals to their names, you want to use `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, where the key will be animal and the value will be its name, example:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> animalNames;
animalNames["cat"] = "molly";
```

Then later when youw ill iterate through `std::vector<std::string>` you will just check if the word you are currently iterating through does exist as a key in your map and replace it with its value.

Comment: wow, thanks guys, maybe this is a bit complex for me - i don't really understand the first line of code or what it does but i'll try and look into it.  thanks